# Answer my own question if I prefer the answers in the comments to submitted answers?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/what-happened-to-agents-brown-and-jones) and received two comments from user [Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/richard) which answer the question to my liking. Moreover, the comments answer the question better than the single submitted answer. I have asked the commenter to post an answer so I can accept it but he declined.

I have since done some more research based on the tip from the comments and found a few links to add to the information from the comments. My research didn't yield much (in this specific case, a confirmation of the comments at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_%28The_Matrix%29#Agents_Jones_and_Brown) and a [random forum post](http://the-causality.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3302) which also confirms the comments).

Should I post an answer as community wiki so I don't get credit for the commenter's work, post an answer as myself since I did additional research, or keep waiting for an additional answer (possibly downvoting the existing answer that I don't think is good)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. What you did was pretty much in full accordance with etiquette (not that it's codified, but it's what I try to adhere to).

   - Encourage the commenter to produce an answer.
   - If they explicitly deny, add some info of your own, and post an answer including a hat-tip to original commenter.
2. BTW, from personal POV, I have definitely done that before (added comments when I had useful answer-leading info but either didn't have enough info to make it into an answer I was happy with, or didn't have time to bother writing up the answer). From that perspective, I can definitely state that I viewed it very positively when people took those comments and based answers on them (especially if they followed both points of etiquette outlined above).
3. Do **not** bother with Community Wiki. You write an answer and that's an effort worth the rep gain.

   The main point of CW is to allow people to edit extensively-community-collaborated answers, which isn't even an issue anymore due to the Edit Suggestion feature for low-rep users. So CW is not very useful.

Comment: The sole reason I've ever used CW is when reposting someone else's (old) comment as an answer. And that's only because of my semi-OCD about leaving questions "unanswered" when there's a perfectly good answer sitting there.

Comment: @Richard:
I've used Community Wiki that way myself. Seemed to have often happened where someone answered their own question in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely you can. Posting your own answer is [positively encouraged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). On top of that, you've apparently done some original research which you can use to supplement the info I put into the comments. You may wish to add an acknowledgement if you use some info from a comment out of pure courtesy.

For the record, the only good reasons for posting something like this as a "[community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)" would be where you've literally done no work whatsoever and simply wish to identify that an answer exists.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I had recently seen a [similar question on Mathematics Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) so I was wondering if the sci fi community had a different policy. If my research had yielded something more definitive (I was hoping for a video or screenshot of Agent Brown or Jones in *The Matrix Online*) I would have simply answered it myself, but the sources I found aren't great so I don't think I'm adding much. But it's still better than the existing "answer".